# How do I make the output shapefile from a query be named by its corresponding value in the loop using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, filepath, shapefile, arcpy

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
for lyr in m.listLayers("POP_ACS17"):
   if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
       for value in listnumbers.split(','):
           lyr.definitionQuery = "COLUMN=" + num
           output_path=r'C:/ArcGIS/Projects/Value_by_Value/'+ num
           arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion('POP_ACS17',output_path)
```

How do i create a shapefile name in the folder based on the query result, and not the same name "POP_ACS17" multiple times? Instead something like num + "_POPACS17" and so on. When i type

```
arcpy.FeatureClasstoShapefile_conversion('POP_ACS17', num + "_"+ outputh_path)
```

it does not work. i get an error message

```
 ERROR 000732: Output Folder: Dataset C:/ArcGIS/Projects/Value_by_Value/1.0/1.0_PCT_POP_ACS17 does not exist or is not supported
```

All I want to do is just have my output renamed by the corresponding value in the loop underscore and the default name that it already gives which is 'POP_ACS17'

so i want

```
1.0_POP_ACS17.shp in folder 1.0
2.0_POP_ACS17.shp in folder 2.0
3.0_POP_ACS17.shp in folder 3.0
```

if not then

```
POP_ACS17_1.0 in folder 1.0
POP_ACS17_2.0 in folder 2.0
POP_ACS17_3.0 in folder 3.0
```

and so on... It does not matter which order as long as I know how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion('PCT_POP_ACS17', output_path)
```

do.....

```
 arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion("_PCT_POP_ACS17", output_path, value+"_PCT_POP_ACS17.shp")
```

make sure you add .shp otherwise each output will appear in your project file.